# How to retrieve the selected file after the user has pressed the Tauri Mac shortcut?

Tags: macos, rust, tauri

I am trying to obtain the file path when the user selects a file and presses "Cmd+Shift+R" in the finder.

I have successfully registered the shortcut, and it is working. However, I am unsure of how to obtain the file path of the selected file.

```rust
#![cfg_attr(not(debug_assertions), windows_subsystem = "windows")]

use tauri::GlobalShortcutManager;

#[tauri::command]
fn greet(name: &str) -> String {
    format!("Hello ->, {}!", name)
}

fn main() {
    // setup the shortcut
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .setup(|app| {
            // #[cfg(target_os = "macos")]
            // app.set_activation_policy(tauri::ActivationPolicy::Accessory);

            let mut shortcut = app.global_shortcut_manager();
            shortcut
                .register("Cmd+Shift+R", move || {
                    println!("Cmd+Shift+R pressed");
                    
                })
                .unwrap_or_else(|err| println!("{:?}", err));

            Ok(())
        })
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![greet])
        .build(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while building tauri application")
        .run(|_app_handle, event| match event {
            tauri::RunEvent::ExitRequested { api, .. } => {
                api.prevent_exit();
            }
            _ => {}
        })
}
```

Update 1:

Currently, I am testing AppleScript using the command 'tell application "Finder" to get selection'.